# Regex for minimum and maximum amount of words with rule

Tags: regex, validation

Working on a name-surname validator. We get entries by people with more than one name. I am looking for a solution.

Old regex: `/[a-zA-Z]{2,}\s[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/` (Works for 1 name - 1 surname)

I am confused with part `{2,}` that it counts recurrence of pattern in the word, but I want it to count the words -> `{2,4}` for minimum 2 and maximum 4 words that fits the rule.

This doesn't work: `/[a-zA-Z\s]{2,}\w$/`

Comment: [a-zA-Z]{2,} means that it should match at least 2 characters from [a-zA-Z]

Comment: @Kevin Correct, so I want to put a counter for word itself, not the recurrence within word, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching 2-4 words, where a "word" matches 2 or more chars A-Za-z:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2,}(?:\s[a-zA-Z]{2,}){1,3}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0zVcsc/1)

Note that the current character ranges are pretty strict for names.

You might also write it matching 1+ word characters, but it would still be limited:

```
^\w+(?:\s+\w+){1,3}$
```

Comment: This did the trick thanks for quick reply. I will inspect the solution.